# SQL Server - Traer datos extras con un Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla con diferentes terminales. En la misma se registra el numero de terminal y sus diferentes mediciones cada 15 minutos (es decir, en la tabla se va a repetir el numero de terminal muchas veces, pero cada registro con diferente fechahora). Ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, lo que yo necesito traer los datos de la ultima medición para cada terminal. Probé algo asi:

```
select terminal, max(fechahora) as 'Ultima medicion' from lecturas group by terminal order by max(fechahora) desc
```

Y obviamente me trae esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Pero como hago ahora para traer los otros valores de cada una de esas mediciones? Es decir, yo necesito una tabla como la primera, pero solo con la ultima medicion para cada terminal (Habria un solo registro por terminal).

Gracias!

Comment: Supongo que por los otros valores te referis a los que correponderian a esa ultima medicion?

Comment: Exacto, los valores de medición correspondientes a la medicion para ese terminal a esa hora (Como se ven en la primera tabla).

Comment: agregas los campos extras dentro del `group by` y lo tomas también en el `select`

Comment: @VictorPerdomo eso te va a agrupar por todos los campos, y va a traer cualquier cosa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para traer los datos que te faltan, solo tenes que volver a joinear esa consulta con la tabla original.

Como lo que quieres es exactamente esa fila, tu condición de join son las dos columnas que ya trajiste, para asegurarte que los datos son de esas filas.

Entonces el query quedaría algo así:

```
Select b.* from (
select terminal, max(fechahora) as 'medicion' from lecturas group by terminal ) a left join lecturas b on a.terminal = b.terminal and a.medicion = b.fechahora 
Order by b.fechahora desc
```

Comment: Sos un maldito crack. Ahora entiendo la logica tambien. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Te hago una consulta. Tenés idea si podemos obtener el mismo resultado pero utilizando "CROSS APPLY" en vez del "JOIN"? Para mejorar la performance.

Comment: @ZottoSL ni idea. Y habria que ver que dice el explain plan. tal vez haga falta algun indice.